# lucene ignore queries on fields other than default

Tags: java, lucene

i have 2 indexes, one for meta data and one for text, i want to be able to remove all field searches in the query and only use the default fields that the user searched, ie "help AND title:carpool" i want only the help part, ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Traverse over tree of BooleanQuery and remove entries related Term("help")

Comment: any sites/suggestions where to look to do this?

Answer (score 1):

This is a ballpark of what your code should look like:

```
public static void removeNonDefault(BooleanQuery query, String defaultField) {
    List<BooleanClause> clauses = (List<BooleanClause>)query.clauses();
    Iterator<BooleanClause> iter = clauses.iterator();
    while(iter.hasNext()) {
        BooleanClause clause = iter.next();
        Query subQuery = clause.getQuery();

        if(subQuery instanceof BooleanQuery) {
            removeNonDefault((BooleanQuery)subQuery, defaultField);

        } else if(subQuery instanceof TermQuery) {
            if (!((TermQuery) subQuery).getTerm().field().equals(defaultField)) {
                iter.remove();
            }

        }
    }
}
```

What this does is removes `TermQuery`s with the non-default field from the `BooleanQuery`, and recurses down into sub-boolean queries.

Note that this code is not complete. Depending on your situation, there might be more types of queries you should worry about, like phrase queries and constant score range queries.

Make sure to do `query.rewrite()` before you call this function, to convert any wildcard queries to boolean queries.